# css style definition

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using style definitions like

```
.detail-navi-contents div.tab-active, .detail-navi-contents div.tab-inactive { }
```

is there any better way to write this definition? Or it ok so

Comment: Seems fine to me, what did you think was wrong with it? PS. You may also try [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? If you're getting both `inactive` **and** `active`, then why select on them?

Try:

```
.detail-navi-contents div { }
```

Comment: There are also some other DIV under detail-navi-contents

Comment: @user160820 Ah, then the only way you can simplify what you have is add a class to both `tab-active` and `tab-inactive` classes and call it `.tab`, then you can do `details-navi-contents div.tab {}`